# I accidentally deleted "winnt.h" how i can get it back?

Tags: c++

I deleted winnt.h because I thought it will re-download itself after I update it or something but it didn't and now I'm stuck without winnt.h and I need it to compile one project. Any help? Where I can get it or how I can get it via an update or something.

Comment: Reinstall the Windows SDK. And make backups.

Comment: Check your recycle bin?

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, winnt.h is not something that is shipped with Windows and would somehow be automatically updated. It comes with a Windows Kit or Visual Studio or the like.

Comment: Michael Gear, already did it, doesn't work sadly.

Comment: @xXTurner What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Those files are part of a toolkit that is readily downloadable, available, and installable on any computer running a modern version of Windows.

Comment: reinstall [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and/or Visual Studio

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, well I tried it but it won't re-download the needed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by going to Visual Studio Installer, then unchecking all windows sdk's versions, waiting to uninstall them, then check them again and wait to install.